how can i fuse embeddings in a manner such that it increase efficiency and score?
I've been working on a problem where the goal is to supplement traditional embeddings with LLM-generated embeddings (I'm using the last_hidden_state for this purpose). So far, I've tried simply concatenating them and using a cross-attention mechanism. While concatenating the embeddings yields similar results to using traditional embeddings alone (and the score is definitely not better), the cross-attention mechanism unexpectedly degraded the performance. Are there other methods that could potentially improve the score? Code is provided below:
Code for Simple Concatenation:
    def forward(self, depot_xy, node_xy_demand_tw, llm_embeddings):
        moe_loss = 0
        
        # Get traditional embeddings
        if isinstance(self.embedding_depot, MoE) or isinstance(self.embedding_node, MoE):
            embedded_depot, loss_depot = self.embedding_depot(depot_xy)
            embedded_node, loss_node = self.embedding_node(node_xy_demand_tw)
            moe_loss = moe_loss + loss_depot + loss_node
        else:
            embedded_depot = self.embedding_depot(depot_xy)
            embedded_node = self.embedding_node(node_xy_demand_tw)

        # Project LLM embeddings and normalize
        # print(320, self.llm_projection[0].weight.dtype, llm_embeddings.dtype)
        projected_llm = self.llm_projection(llm_embeddings)
        projected_llm = self.layer_norm(projected_llm)
        
        # Combine traditional embeddings with LLM embeddings
        depot_combined = embedded_depot + projected_llm[:, :1, :]  # For depot
        node_combined = embedded_node + projected_llm[:, 1:, :]   # For nodes
        
        out = torch.cat((depot_combined, node_combined), dim=1)

        for layer in self.layers:
            out, loss = layer(out)
            moe_loss = moe_loss + loss

        return out, moe_loss

Code for Cross attention based fusion with Cross attention class:
########################################
# CROSS ATTENTION
########################################

class CrossAttentionFusion(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embedding_dim, head_num, qkv_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.head_num = head_num
        
        # Cross attention layers for traditional -> LLM
        self.Wq_trad = nn.Linear(embedding_dim, head_num * qkv_dim, bias=False).to(dtype=torch.bfloat16)
        self.Wk_llm = nn.Linear(embedding_dim, head_num * qkv_dim, bias=False).to(dtype=torch.bfloat16)
        self.Wv_llm = nn.Linear(embedding_dim, head_num * qkv_dim, bias=False).to(dtype=torch.bfloat16)
        
        # Cross attention layers for LLM -> traditional
        self.Wq_llm = nn.Linear(embedding_dim, head_num * qkv_dim, bias=False).to(dtype=torch.bfloat16)
        self.Wk_trad = nn.Linear(embedding_dim, head_num * qkv_dim, bias=False).to(dtype=torch.bfloat16)
        self.Wv_trad = nn.Linear(embedding_dim, head_num * qkv_dim, bias=False).to(dtype=torch.bfloat16)
        
        # Output projections
        self.W_out_trad = nn.Linear(head_num * qkv_dim, embedding_dim).to(dtype=torch.bfloat16)
        self.W_out_llm = nn.Linear(head_num * qkv_dim, embedding_dim).to(dtype=torch.bfloat16)
        
        # Layer norms
        self.norm_trad = nn.LayerNorm(embedding_dim).to(dtype=torch.bfloat16)
        self.norm_llm = nn.LayerNorm(embedding_dim).to(dtype=torch.bfloat16)

    def forward(self, trad_emb, llm_emb):
        # Cross attention: traditional -> LLM
        # print(f"trad_emb dtype: {trad_emb.dtype}, shape: {trad_emb.shape}")
        # print(f"llm_emb dtype: {llm_emb.dtype}, shape: {llm_emb.shape}")
        # print(f"Wq_trad type: {self.Wq_trad.weight.dtype}, shape: {self.Wq_trad.weight.shape}")
        q_trad = reshape_by_heads(self.Wq_trad(trad_emb), self.head_num)
        k_llm = reshape_by_heads(self.Wk_llm(llm_emb), self.head_num)
        v_llm = reshape_by_heads(self.Wv_llm(llm_emb), self.head_num)
        
        trad_attends_llm = multi_head_attention(q_trad, k_llm, v_llm)
        trad_fused = self.W_out_trad(trad_attends_llm)
        trad_out = self.norm_trad(trad_emb + trad_fused)
        
        # Cross attention: LLM -> traditional
        q_llm = reshape_by_heads(self.Wq_llm(llm_emb), self.head_num)
        k_trad = reshape_by_heads(self.Wk_trad(trad_emb), self.head_num)
        v_trad = reshape_by_heads(self.Wv_trad(trad_emb), self.head_num)
        
        llm_attends_trad = multi_head_attention(q_llm, k_trad, v_trad)
        llm_fused = self.W_out_llm(llm_attends_trad)
        llm_out = self.norm_llm(llm_emb + llm_fused)
        
        # Combine the cross-attended features
        fused_embeddings = trad_out + llm_out
        
        return fused_embeddings


########################################
# ENCODER
########################################

class MTL_Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, **model_params):
        super().__init__()
        self.model_params = model_params
        embedding_dim = self.model_params['embedding_dim']
        hidden_dim = self.model_params['ff_hidden_dim']
        encoder_layer_num = self.model_params['encoder_layer_num']
        head_num = self.model_params['head_num']
        qkv_dim = self.model_params['qkv_dim']
        llama_hidden_size = 4096  # Llama-2 7B hidden size
        
        # Project Llama embeddings to the model's embedding dimension with dtype torch.bfloat16
        self.llm_projection = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(llama_hidden_size, hidden_dim),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(hidden_dim, embedding_dim)
        ).to(dtype=torch.bfloat16)

        
        # Add layer normalization for better embedding fusion
        self.layer_norm = nn.LayerNorm(embedding_dim).to(dtype=torch.bfloat16)
        self.layer_norm_trad = nn.LayerNorm(embedding_dim).to(dtype=torch.bfloat16)

        if self.model_params['num_experts'] > 1 and "Raw" in self.model_params['expert_loc']:
            self.embedding_depot = MoE(input_size=2, output_size=embedding_dim, 
                                     num_experts=self.model_params['num_experts'],
                                     k=self.model_params['topk'], T=1.0, 
                                     noisy_gating=True, 
                                     routing_level=self.model_params['routing_level'],
                                     routing_method=self.model_params['routing_method'], 
                                     moe_model="Linear")
            self.embedding_node = MoE(input_size=5, output_size=embedding_dim, 
                                    num_experts=self.model_params['num_experts'],
                                    k=self.model_params['topk'], T=1.0, 
                                    noisy_gating=True, 
                                    routing_level=self.model_params['routing_level'],
                                    routing_method=self.model_params['routing_method'], 
                                    moe_model="Linear")
        else:
            self.embedding_depot = nn.Linear(2, embedding_dim)
            self.embedding_node = nn.Linear(5, embedding_dim)

        # Cross-attention fusion module
        self.cross_attention_fusion = CrossAttentionFusion(
            embedding_dim=embedding_dim,
            head_num=head_num,
            qkv_dim=qkv_dim
        )
        
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList([EncoderLayer(i, **model_params) 
                                   for i in range(encoder_layer_num)])

    def forward(self, depot_xy, node_xy_demand_tw, llm_embeddings):
        moe_loss = 0
        
        # Get traditional embeddings
        if isinstance(self.embedding_depot, MoE) or isinstance(self.embedding_node, MoE):
            embedded_depot, loss_depot = self.embedding_depot(depot_xy)
            embedded_node, loss_node = self.embedding_node(node_xy_demand_tw)
            moe_loss = moe_loss + loss_depot + loss_node
        else:
            embedded_depot = self.embedding_depot(depot_xy)
            embedded_node = self.embedding_node(node_xy_demand_tw)
        
        # Combine depot and node embeddings
        traditional_embeddings = torch.cat((embedded_depot, embedded_node), dim=1).to(dtype=torch.bfloat16)
        
        # Project and normalize LLM embeddings
        projected_llm = self.llm_projection(llm_embeddings)
        projected_llm = self.layer_norm(projected_llm)
        
        # Normalize traditional embeddings
        traditional_embeddings = self.layer_norm_trad(traditional_embeddings)
        
        # Apply cross-attention fusion
        fused_embeddings = self.cross_attention_fusion(
            traditional_embeddings,
            projected_llm
        )
        
        # Pass through encoder layers
        out = fused_embeddings
        for layer in self.layers:
            out, loss = layer(out)
            moe_loss = moe_loss + loss

        return out, moe_loss

and following is how I'm getting the LLM embeddings,
                with torch.no_grad():
                    outputs = self.llama(**inputs)
                    # Use the last hidden state's [CLS] token
                    new_embeddings = outputs.hidden_states[-1][:, 0, :]

Am I doing something wrong? Or Do the traditional embeddings even need ones generated by LLM?
